# Rebasing - can't get odbcint.dll to load at its preferred base

Tags: dll, odbc, rebase

The default base address for an `.exe` built in Visual Studio is 0x00400000.

The default base address for `d3dx9_30.dll` and `odbcint.dll` (which both live in `%windir%\system32`) is also 0x00400000.  So by default, `exe`s that link to either of these dlls will have a runtime address collision.  The OS automatically relocates the `dll` to a different base addresses and fixes up pointers as needed, and I can see this happening when I attach the VS debugger: The relocated module gets an exclamation icon overlay.

Rebasing system DLLs is a really bad idea, not to mention nearly impossible to do on user systems.  So I have decided to rebase my `exe`s to prevent this address collision and thus prevent runtime rebasing.

If I change my client EXE to a different base address to move it out of `d3dx9_30.dll`'s way, it works fine: no address collision, no relocation, no fixups.

But if I change my server EXEs to a different base address to move them out of `odbcint.dll`'s way, it does not work.

`odbcint.dll` is 0x17000 bytes in memory and prefers base address 0x00400000.  I tried basing my EXEs at 0x00420000, then at 0x00660000.  Still `odbcint.dll` gets relocated at runtime.  I profiled with `depends.exe`, which showed that there is no other module attempting to claim this address before `odbcint.dll` loads.

Does anyone have a theory explaining why I can't get `odbcint.dll` to load at its preferred address?

`Update`:
vadump shows that by the time I enter main() the memory at 0x00400000-0x00470000 is claimed as 'UNKNOWN_MAPPED'.  I have been unable to find more information about what exactly this means.  I presume that some system dll is reserving this memory at load time; my debugging-fu is not strong enough to discover which, why, or precisely when.

Answer (score 1):

If you download VADump (available in the [Windows Resource Kit:](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displaylang=en)), you can see exactly what module is hitting those pages and causing it to miss its address. (Run vadump -op pid.)

You didn't say what OS you're working on, but on Vista/2K8+ you should also know about [ASLR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.04.vistakernel.aspx).

Comment: Timbo, if you like the answer, select it as the best answer.

Comment: It's helpful and has taken me further along the path to a solution, but my question remains unanswered.  Note the Update in the original question.